# How to query in sqlite for a particular date?

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

When I give select date('now', 'start of month') sqlite returns first day of the current month,But When I try

`select * from mytable where trandate in ( select date(;now', 'start of day'))`

it returns no rows all the data id present for the day.
When I use 
select * from mutable where trandate = 20140401 it returns correctly. But I want to query on dates which I do not know

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE trandate IN (
  SELECT date(;

now', '-9 years', '+5 days'))
```

In this case I do not know which date will be 9 years back + 5 days
Please tell me how to query for dates using modifiers such as above in search criteria

Comment: What is the format of the values in the `trandate` column?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is "start of month", not "start of day":

```
select *
from mytable
where trandate in ( select date('now', 'start of month'));
```

I assume you know that you don't need the subselect:

```
select *
from mytable
where trandate = date('now', 'start of month');
```